# Strange issue starting spark-shell: screen block

Tags: apache-spark

When I start spark-shell with yarn Im getting a strange issue. The screen stops here:

[image]

No erros, just this screen. Do you know know what issue can be?

The only tow spark files I configured was spark-env.sh:

```
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=192.168.1.110
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=192.168.1.110
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=4G
```

And slaves:

```
192.168.1.110
192.168.1.111
```

I wait for 30minutes and it the screen gets unblocked but now Im having some errors:

```
16/05/25 11:13:43 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.net.ConnectException: Call From master/192.168.1.110 to 0.0.0.0:8032                                    failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; F                                   or more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor12.newInstance(Unknown Source                                   )
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC                                   onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:791)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:731)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1472)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEng                                   ine.java:232)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.getNewApplication(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationClientProtocolPB                                   ClientImpl.getNewApplication(ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:217)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces                                   sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryI                                   nvocationHandler.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocat                                   ionHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.getNewApplication(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.getNewApplicati                                   on(YarnClientImpl.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.createApplicati                                   on(YarnClientImpl.java:214)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:13                                   2)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(Y                                   arnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.                                   scala:144)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:530)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:                                   1017)
        at $line3.$read$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:15)
        at $line3.$read$$iwC.<init>(<console>:24)
        at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:26)
        at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:30)
        at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval$.<init>(<console>:7)
        at $line3.$eval$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.                                   java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces                                   sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:                                   1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:                                   1346)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840                                   )
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:8                                   57)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.sca                                   la:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply                                   (SparkILoopInit.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply                                   (SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoop                                   Init.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$Spark                                   ILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:974)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.s                                   cala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkIL                                   oopInit.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:                                   64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$Spark                                   ILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:991)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$Spark                                   ILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$Spark                                   ILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClass                                   Loader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$pr                                   ocess(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.                                   java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces                                   sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSub                                   mit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:18                                   1)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717                                   )
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout                                   .java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:494)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:6                                   07)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:70                                   5)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:368)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1521)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1438)
        ... 64 more
16/05/25 11:13:43 WARN MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not runni                                   ng
java.net.ConnectException: Call From sgd34.dei.uc.pt/10.17.0.88 to 0.0.0.0:8032                                    failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; F                                   or more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor12.newInstance(Unknown Source                                   )
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC                                   onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:791)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:731)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1472)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEng                                   ine.java:232)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.getNewApplication(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationClientProtocolPB                                   ClientImpl.getNewApplication(ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:217)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces                                   sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryI                                   nvocationHandler.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocat                                   ionHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.getNewApplication(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.getNewApplicati                                   on(YarnClientImpl.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.createApplicati                                   on(YarnClientImpl.java:214)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:13                                   2)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(Y                                   arnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.                                   scala:144)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:530)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:                                   1017)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:15)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:24)
        at <init>(<console>:26)
        at .<init>(<console>:30)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.                                   java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces                                   sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:                                   1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:                                   1346)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840                                   )
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:8                                   57)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.sca                                   la:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply                                   (SparkILoopInit.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply                                   (SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoop                                   Init.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$Spark                                   ILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:974)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.s                                   cala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkIL                                   oopInit.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:                                   64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$Spark                                   ILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:991)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$Spark                                   ILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$Spark                                   ILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClass                                   Loader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$pr                                   ocess(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.                                   java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces                                   sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSub                                   mit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:18                                   1)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717                                   )
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout                                   .java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:494)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:6                                   07)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:70                                   5)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:368)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1521)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1438)
        ... 64 more

java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$.createListenerAndUI(SQLContext.scala                                   :1367)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:101)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct                                   orAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC                                   onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSQLContext(SparkILoop.scala:10                                   28)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:15)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:24)
        at <init>(<console>:26)
        at .<init>(<console>:30)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.                                   java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces                                   sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:                                   1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:                                   1346)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840                                   )
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:8                                   57)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.sca                                   la:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply                                   (SparkILoopInit.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply                                   (SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoop                                   Init.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$Spark                                   ILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:974)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.s                                   cala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkIL                                   oopInit.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:                                   64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$Spark                                   ILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:991)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$Spark                                   ILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$Spark                                   ILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClass                                   Loader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$pr                                   ocess(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.                                   java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces                                   sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSub                                   mit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:18                                   1)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

<console>:16: error: not found: value sqlContext
         import sqlContext.implicits._
                ^
<console>:16: error: not found: value sqlContext
         import sqlContext.sql
```

Comment: Is your HDFS up and running ?

Comment: did you try to press the enter key couple of times? there is a known issue, sometimes the `scala>` prompt appears only after you press enter.

Comment: Thanks, HDFS is up and running. And also withe enter the screen dont starts from that image point.